# Twig increment value of Twig variable for one

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to add set body classes using Twig `root_path` variable. Which prints for every page string 'node'.

How I can write condition, `if root_path == 'node'` increment value for 1 so it adds 1 to string node. And for every page increment `node_1`, `node_2`, `node_3` and so on.

Twig is totally new for me, and also sorry if I'm being unclear now.
Tried this, but I guess it totally doesn't make any sense.

```
{% if root_path === 'node' %}

{% set root_path = root_path + 1 %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: How do you determine a new page? Do you have a Twig for loop somewhere? Can you show the code if that is the case. There would be a much simpler answer than the one already posted.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly whether it is a matter of increasing the number of the variable root_path within a page. If so, then you have to make it through some string operators. Here is a possibility:

```
  {% if root_path[0:4] == 'node' %}
  {% set root_path = 'node_' ~ (root_path|split('_', 2)[1] + 1) %}
  {% endif %}

  <p>{{ root_path }}</p> // show node_1

  {% if root_path[0:4] == 'node' %}
    {% set root_path = 'node_' ~ (root_path|split('_', 2)[1] + 1) %}
  {% endif %}

  <p>{{ root_path }}</p> // show node_2
```

If you want to count it over a side, work with a counter within the session.

But in any case, separate the combination of the string and the index and put it together if necessary.

```
<body id=”{{ ‘node_’ ~ counter }}”>
```

Comment: Thank you man! This is exactly what I want almost there.  `{% if root_path[0:4] == 'node' %}
    {% set root_path = 'node_' ~ (root_path|split('_', 2)[1] + 1) %}
  {% endif %}`But as a result I've got for every page path-node-1 class . I wanted to every time it increments for one so every page will have unique number page-node-2 , page-node-3 and so on..

Comment: One way is to use the session in PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865015/how-to-increment-a-counter-each-page-load-in-php

Comment: Thanks for effort man , but it doesn't solves my problem . Just need to add something specific for every page class beside node-..

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify a bit your question for example by showing how looks your variable containing pages and the expected markup.

If your goal is to traverse a tree of links to generate an index, you may be interested by an extension I developed.

https://github.com/ninsuo/jordan-tree

```
{% tree item in menu %}
  {% if treeloop.first %}<ul>{% endif %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
        {% subtree item.children %}
    </li>
  {% if treeloop.last %}</ul>{% endif %}
{% endtree %}
```